# Custom SQL for a cart feature

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a cart table.

It consist of:

```
CartID, CartProductID, CartSessionID, CartUserID....
```

User can come & add to cart the product & stores sessionid() & UserID (if logged in else stores as '0' zero)

On cart the SQL I'm using is:

```
SELECT c.*
     , p.ProductName
     , p.ProductID
     , p.ProductMainImage
     , p.ProductSellingPrice
     , p.ProductCode
     , SUM(c.CartProductQty) totalqty
     , SUM(c.CartProductQty * p.ProductSellingPrice) productotal
     , SUM((CartProductSellingPrice * CartProductQty) * CartProductTax/100) AS TotalTax  
  FROM Carts c
  JOIN Products p
    ON c.CartProductID = p.ProductID 
 WHERE (c.CartSessionID = '$session' OR c.CartUserID = '$securityuserID')    
   AND (c.CartProductQty > 0) 
 GROUP 
    BY c.CartProductID 
 ORDER 
    BY c.CartID DESC
```

The code to look at is WHERE CLAUSE i.e.

````
WHERE (Carts.CartSessionID = '$session' OR Carts.CartUserID = '$userID') 
AND  (Carts.CartProductQty > 0) 
GROUP BY Carts.CartProductID 
ORDER BY Carts.CartID DESC ```
````

so `$session` is basically `sessionid()` & `$userID` if user logged inn their ID else 0. ( i have this the php code on above page for how sessionid & userid is achieved but its not needed here.)

So now if any fresh user comes & add product to cart without logging in then record will be.
Some other records added as well.

```
CartID, CartProductID, CartSessionID, CartUserID
1       7              abc             0
2       8              abc             2
3       4              xxx             1
4       3              cvb             3
5       1              zxc             2
6       8              rfg             0
7       8              qwe             0
8       8              mmm             0
```

Now if any other user with 0 can still view others record. How do we stop this? Is it something to make it NULL? If so then what should the SQL be?

OR

In simple words, I want to display products of users whatever they have added only irrespestive of logged in or not.

Comment: Make the Cart key of NON Logged in User Carts the session id and not `0` then. Then it shoud be unique to the Non Logged in individual

Comment: @RiggsFolly i didn't understand.

Comment: You said the key to the Cart of All users not yet logged in is `0` Zero. So purchases of all non logged in user go into the same cart.... Right? So make the key for the Cart be the `sessionid()` as everyone should get a unique session.... or sessions would not work. And everyone gets a session whether they are logged in or not (**I assume**)

Comment: did u mean just to use sessionid in where clause and not use userid? so this is just for displaying in cart. but like vise we do store userid right?

Comment: the logics sounds good. i just made it complicated myself for cart thing. @RiggsFolly thank you. god bless

Comment: @RiggsFolly, i just found a loop hole in this system. After a user logs out the sessionid is cleared & new sessionid is created. Thus whatever he added can not be showed again after logout and login in again cause we are never using userID in where clause. How do we solve this?

Comment: Also if user adds product into cart when logged in, should always display on cart even if sessions are different.